# Getting string results to INSERT into database from foreach loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, checkout

I am creating a checkout system and I am trying to figure out how I am going to insert the string from the results of my foreach loop that displays which products were chosen, the quantity, and and pertinent data about them.

The way I have the shipping information in place is I validate it and if it passes, I allow it to be inserted once the order is placed. Like this:

```
if(Input::exists()) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'fullname' => array(
                'required' => true,
                'min' => 2,
                'max' => 50
            )

if($validation->passed()) {
            if(isset($_POST['create'])){ 
                $fullname = trim( $_POST['customer_name'] );

<div class="field">
                                        <label class="paddingleft" for="fullname">Full Name</label>
                                    <div class="center"><input type="text"  class="biginputbarinline" name="fullname" value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('firstname')); ?>" required></div>
                                    </div>
```

I am wanting to INSERT all of the data on my page at once and not do seperate INSERT submissions. I have the shipping info, payment info and Order confirmation all on the same page. I will not be storing the payment info in my database. So that is irrelevant to this question. The Order confirmation is where the order will be displayed and I want that info to send in to my database with my shipping info.

The part I am really confused with is how to INSERT the actual string this foreach loop displays. This is how I have the Order confirmation section as of now..

```
<div class="checkoutconfirmationcontainer">
                                            <?php foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                                                    $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                                        ?>
                                        <span class="tealmedium"><?php echo $product['quantity'] . " - "  . $products[$product_id]['name'] . $message; ?></span><br><br><br>


                                            <div class="floatleft"><div class="smallerimgcontainer">
                                                    <?php
                                                        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products");
                                                        if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                            $products[$row['product_id']] = $row;

                                                        if($row['image'] == ""){
                                                                echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/coming_soon.png' alt='Coming Soon'>";
                                                        } else {
                                                                echo "<img class='sizedimg' src='/productpics/".$row['img']."' alt='Product Picture'>";
                                                        }
                                                        echo "<br><br><br><br>";
                                                        }
                                                    ?>
                                            </div></div>
                                            <div class="checkoutitemsummary">
                                                <?php echo "<a href='./viewProduct.php?view_product=$id'>" . $product['name'];?><?php echo $products[$product_id]['name']; ?> </a>
                                                    <p><span class="redprice"><?php echo '$' . $products[$product_id]['price'] . "<br />"; }?></span></p>
                                            </div>
```

How could I get the foreach loop produced string to be inserted into my database?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear - what is it exactly you're trying to get in the database? Is the problem that you want it all to be inserted at one time, instead of lots of separate queries? If so, you probably need to use a transaction.

Comment: I am not sure how to INSERT the string my foreach loop produces. Say 2 different products were in the checkout. My loop would produce the quantity added, the product name, etc. I'm not sure how to write this so that output is sent in to my database when they click 'send payment now'.  What do you mean use a transaction?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to achieve...you could store array of `$products` in a session/cookie or in the database somewhere, and have a button that goes to a specific route, which fetches those values and converts it into an order? Take a look at how other checkout systems handle this, e.g. with Magento

Comment: I am storing the products chosen in a session. All of my products are in my database. I am looking to send the products that were chosen to a different table in my database called orders, once the order has been placed.